# How can I make pairs of the partner_name values in the given dataset?

Tags: python, business-intelligence

| user_id | partner_name | order_sequence |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | Star Bucks | 1 |
| 2 | KFC | 2 |
| 2 | MCD | 3 |
| 6 | Coffee Store | 1 |
| 6 | MCD | 2 |
| 9 | KFC | 1 |

I am trying to figure out what two restaurant combinations occur the most often. For instance, user with user_id 2 went to star bucks, KFC, and MCD, so I want a two-dimensional array that has [[star bucks, KFC],[KFC, MCD].

However, each time the user_id changes, for instance, in lines 3 and 4, the code should skip adding this combination.

Also, if a user has only one entry in the table, for instance, user with user_id 9, then this user should not be added to the list because he did not visit two or more restaurants.

The final result I am expecting for this table are:
[[Star Bucks, KFC], [KFC,MCD], [Coffee Store, MCD]]

I have written the following lines of code but so far, I am unable to crack it.
Requesting help!

```
arr1 = []
arr2 = []
for idx,x in enumerate(df['order_sequence']):
    if x!=1:
        arr1.append(df['partner_name'][idx])
        arr1.append(df['partner_name'][idx+1])
        arr2.append(arr1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use `.groupby()` and `zip()`:

```
res = [
    pair
    for _, sdf in df.groupby("user_id")
    for pair in zip(sdf["partner_name"], sdf["partner_name"].iloc[1:])
]
```

Result for the sample dataframe:

```
[('Star Bucks', 'KFC'), ('KFC', 'MCD'), ('Coffee Store', 'MCD')]
```

Or try

```
res = (
    df.groupby("user_id")["partner_name"].agg(list)
    .map(lambda l: list(zip(l, l[1:])))
    .sum()
)
```

with the same result.

Might be, that you have to sort the dataframe before:

```
df = df.sort_values(["user_id", "order_sequence"])
```